# JOptionPane title bar icon

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'd like to replace the icon in a JOptionPane title bar (as it currently shows the default Java coffee logo).

I tried the following:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Text", "Login",
 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, ImageCacheProvider
   .instance.getImageIcon("img/an image.png"));
```

It replaces the icon in the window but not the one in the title bar:

[image: Screenshot title bar]

Is there any approach to change the icon in the title bar or alternatively to hide the default Java icon without having to implement a JDialog class?

Thanks a bunch!
Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("d:/temp/CheckBox.gif");  
JOptionPane jp = new JOptionPane("Session Expired - Please Re Login"),   
  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,   
  JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,   
  icon);  
JDialog dialog = jp.createDialog(null, "Session Expired - Please Re Login");
((Frame)dialog.getParent()).setIconImage(((ImageIcon)icon).getImage());  
dialog.setResizable(true);  
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me:

```
private static final Image myImage = ...;

/*
 * Copied from javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Component, Object, String, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static int showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType,
        int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue) throws HeadlessException {
    JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, messageType, optionType, icon, options, initialValue);

    pane.setInitialValue(initialValue);
    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);

    // Added this line
    dialog.setIconImage(myImage);

    pane.selectInitialValue();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.dispose();

    Object selectedValue = pane.getValue();

    if (selectedValue == null)
        return JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION;
    if (options == null) {
        if (selectedValue instanceof Integer)
            return ((Integer) selectedValue).intValue();
        return JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION;
    }
    for (int counter = 0, maxCounter = options.length; counter < maxCounter; counter++) {
        if (options[counter].equals(selectedValue))
            return counter;
    }
    return JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION;
}
```